# After midnight end time NOT a multi-day event?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Question about modifying the full calendar script found here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar ( hope I tagged this right, seems to be a lot of posts regarding the script )

With monthly view, an event that starts on saturday at 10pm and ends on sunday at 1am results in an event that will stretch the event over two days. Technically, that makes sense as 1am Sunday is on Sunday:)

However, it's visually deceiving and actually not a true representation of an event that ends just shortly after midnight. Nobody would consider this kind of an event a multi-day event.

Course, I am using this script as a part of a Joomla component - gCalendar, so this might already be an option that just wasn't incorporated into the component. If not, any suggestions as to how to modify the code so that events that end after midnight are not considered multiple day events?

Comment: How long after midnight does a time have to be before it's considered *really* to be a multiday event? In your example, if the event started at 11pm and ended at 2am, should it be a Sunday event rather than a Saturday one? It feels like there might be "intuitive" notions here that are difficult to translate into usable code.

Comment: I think it's pretty standard to assume that in most cases, it's common for things than span across to a sunday are still considered 1 day, saturday night events.

eg: going out to a bar on saturday night, you don't consider getting home at 3am to mean you went out sunday night as well.

eg: a concert that starts on saturday but ends at 1am on sunday isn't advertizes as a two-day event.

So, usable code in my mind would be easy in concept: checkbox to make/force this as a one day event, the day being the day that the START time falls in.

How to program this I have no idea:)